# What's the correct way of enabling buffer_request behavior in pylibmc?

Tags: python, memcached

If I run following script, it throws an exception at set.

buffertest.py

```
import pylibmc
mc = pylibmc.Client(['localhost:11211'], behaviors={'buffer_requests': True})
mc.set('key1', 'value1')
print 'Reaching here'
print mc.get('key1')
```

Output :

```
root@shady:~# python buffertest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "buffertest.py", line 3, in <module>
    mc.set('key1', 'value1')
_pylibmc.MemcachedError: error 32 from memcached_set: SUCCESS
```

If I catch that exception, then get throws an error:

```
import pylibmc
mc = pylibmc.Client(['localhost:11211'], behaviors={'buffer_requests': True})
try:   
        mc.set('key1', 'value1')
except:
        pass
print 'Reaching here'
print mc.get('key1')
```

Output:

```
root@shady:~# python buffertest.py
Reaching here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "buffertest.py", line 8, in <module>
    print mc.get('key1')
_pylibmc.MemcachedError: error 47 from memcached_get(key1): SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS    DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY
```

Am I using this behavior in a wrong way? My understanding of this behavior is - sets would be buffered at client side and would be flushed to server when first get arrives. Why should it cause a server error?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the binary option to False:

```
mc = pylibmc.Client(['localhost:11211'], binary=False, behaviors={'buffer_requests': True})
```